# How to creat a BOT (copilot) in MS teams that extracts data from excel?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft365, autopilot

i´m trying to creat a BOT (Autopilot) in MS Teams that lookup data from a Excel spreadsheet.

I want a Bot that can be posted in my work Teams, so my friends can use the bot do consult data in the spreadsheet.

For now I just need it could read a two column table. Like: Column A (Names) and Column B (Values), so you can serach by the name and the bot teels you the value.

Is that something possible to be done? And if so, how? I cant find any tutorial in the internet..

Thx for any help.

I´ve tried to creat a flow connected to Excel, but did not success..

If anyone have done it before or know any tutorials will help a lot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Microsoft Graph API to access the Excel data and the Teams Bot Framework to build and deploy the bot.please go through with this documentation for further reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots